# Best approach for data conversion/mapping

Tags: python, oop, properties, data-conversion

The task is to map the fields from one data set to another, some fields require some additional parsing/computation.

(I'm using only a few fields in the examples provided below but there is much more in the original data sets).

### **Approach 1:**

Initially I though to use dict for field mappings and just assign functions to keys that require additional data manipulation:

```
import base64
import hashlib
import json

from datetime import datetime


def str2base64(event):
    md5 = hashlib.md5(event['id'].encode())
    return base64.b64encode(md5.digest())


def ts2iso(event):
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(event['timestamp'])
    return dt.isoformat()


MAPPINGS = {
    'id': id2hash,
    'region': 'site',
    'target': 'host',
    'since': ts2iso
}


def parser(event):
    new = dict()
    for k, v in MAPPINGS.items():
        if callable(v):
            value = v(event)
        else:
            value = event.get(v)
        new[k] = value
    return new


def main():
    for event in events:  # dicts
        event = parser(event)
        print(json.dumps(event, indent=2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't like the fact that I have to add all parsing function at the top so the MAPPING dict can see it and I'm not sure if that's the best approach? Besides I don’t see an easy way to pass default value to `dict.get` in `parser` function.

### **Approach 2 (OOP):**

```
import base64
import hashlib
import json

from datetime import datetime


class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, event):
        self.event = event

    @property
    def id(self):
        md5 = hashlib.md5(self.event['id'].encode())
        return base64.b64encode(md5.digest())

    @property
    def region(self):
        return self.event['site']

    @property
    def target(self):
        return self.event['host']

    @property
    def since(self):
        dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(self.event['timestamp'])
        return dt.isoformat()

    def data(self):
        return {
            attr: getattr(self, attr)
            for attr in dir(self)
            if not attr.startswith('__') and attr not in ['event', 'data']
        }


def main():
    for event in events:  # dicts
        event = Event(event).data()
        print(json.dumps(event, indent=2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm sure there is a better way to get all properties (property methods only) to avoid this ugly `data` method? I would like to also avoid adding prefix to relevant methods so I could then filter them with `str.startswith` or something similar.

What would be the best approach for this task? I was also looking at [@functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) from functools but I think it won't be helpful in this case.

Comment: If this is part of a larger application, you should consider a schema definition tool like `marshmallow` for this task. Schema loading and dumping are useful as a way of standardizing how you validate or reform data.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your first approach makes a lot of sense and, if that is important to you, will perform much better than the OO approach. In case you need to process large numbers of events, converting a `dict` to an `object` will certainly be quite CPU intensive. I find it also very explicit and clear.

In the OO approach you would convert from `dict` to `object` *for nothing*. There is no benefit of having an `object`, because all you do later on is converting it to JSON (which you can't do with a custom class unless you write your JSON encoder).

That's why my choice would be option number one, which I would modify slightly like this:

```
class SimpleConverter:

    def __init__(self, key, default=None):
        self.key = key
        self.default = default

    def __call__(self, event):
        return event.get(self.key, self.default)


class TimestampToISO:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def __call__(self, event):
        dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(event[self.key])
        return dt.isoformat()


class StringToBase64:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def __call__(self, event):
        md5 = hashlib.md5(event[self.key].encode())
        return base64.b64encode(md5.digest()).decode()  ## Without .decode() for Python2


def transform_event(event, mapping):
    return {key: convert(event) for key, convert in mapping.items()}


def main(events, mapping):
    for event in events:  # dicts
        event = transform_event(event, mapping)
        print(json.dumps(event, indent=2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mapping = {
        'id': StringToBase64("id"),
        'region': SimpleConverter("site"),
        'target': SimpleConverter("region"),
        'with_default': SimpleConverter("missing_key", "Not missing!"),
        'since': TimestampToISO("timestamp"),
    }
    events = [
        {
            'id': 'test',
            'site': 'X',
            'host': 'Y',
            'timestamp': 1582408754.5111449,
        }
    ]
    main(events, mapping)
```

Which outputs this:

```
{
  "id": "CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g==",
  "region": "X",
  "target": null,
  "with_default": "Not missing!",
  "since": "2020-02-22T22:59:14.511145"
}
```

Notice how with this solution you can reuse all the converter classes for different event keys, which was not possible with pure functions.

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty cool problem you got here, however I feel the solutions are all a bit too code heavy:

```
MAPPINGS = {
    'id': id2hash,
    'region': ('site', 'default_region'),
    'target': ('host', 'default_target'),
    'since': ts2iso
}
# Unpack tuple if action is not callable. Equivalent to event.get(action[0], action[1])
mapped_event = [
    {key: action(event) if callable(action) else event.get(*action)
    for key, action in mapping} for event in events]
```

This solution does exactly what your first approach was but in a lot less lines. I agree this is fairly unreadable, so feel free to reuse only the parts you want (maybe have the dict comprehension in a separate function and call that in the list comp).

If what you wanted to express in your mapping for keys like `'target': 'host'` is: `event.get('target', 'host')`, then the comprehension becomes:

```
mapped_event = [
    {key: action(event) if callable(action) else event.get(key, action)
    for key, action in mapping} for event in events]
```

Comment: Cool but his won't handle default values unless I use `lambda` or something similar in the mapping `dict`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by default value, that ternary `key: action(event) if callable(action) else event.get(action)` does exactly what your `parser` function does in your first approach.

Comment: Yes and that's the problem: `Besides I don’t see an easy way to pass default value to dict.get in parser function.`. So I can't just simply set the value like this at the moment: `MAPPINGS = {'exmaple': 'Yes', ...}`

Comment: Oh okay sorry I didn't realize you were trying to have defaults values too. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer from @matino but here're a few related points that I would like to make:

> I think that your first approach makes a lot of sense and, if that is
>   important to you, will perform much better than the OO approach. In
>   case you need to process large numbers of events, converting a dict to
>   an object will certainly be quite CPU intensive.

Your solution is also using objects and actually a few for a single event?!

> In the OO approach you would convert from dict to object for nothing.
>   There is no benefit of having an object, because all you do later on
>   is converting it to JSON (which you can't do with a custom class
>   unless you write your JSON encoder).

Again your solution is also creating (many) objects and because some fields will default to `None` or `True`/`False`, we actually create an object(s) just to get a value from `dict`:

```
mapping = {
    ...
    'example': SimpleConverter(None, True),
    ...
}
```

In order to make this work with booleans I had to modify the `transform_event` function like this:

```
def transform_event(event, mapping):
    new = dict()
    for key, value in mapping.items():
        if callable(value):
            value = value(event)
        new[key] = value
    return new
```

Field example:

```
mapping = {
    ...
    'example': True,
    ...
}
```

So, now we have a `mapping` dict, function to convert the fields and a few classes for each conversion...

While looking into your solution I decided to improve the `Event` class. I made it iterable so it's easy to convert it to dict, json etc.:

```
class Event(object):
    __slots__ = ('event', 'fields')

    def __init__(self, event):
        self.event = event
        self.fields = [
            'id',
            'region',
            'target',
            'since',
        ]

    def __iter__(self):
        return (self._get(f) for f in self.fields)

    @property
    def id(self):
        md5 = hashlib.md5(self.event['id'].encode())
        return base64.b64encode(md5.digest())

    @property
    def region(self):
        return self.event['site']

    @property
    def target(self):
        return self.event['host']

    @property
    def since(self):
        dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(self.event['timestamp'])
        return dt.isoformat()

    def _get(self, field):
        try:
            return getattr(self, field)
        except AttributeError:
            return self.event.get(field)

    def asdict(self):
        return dict(zip(self.fields, self))
```

So we keep all data in a single object that should be easily extensible, we have immutable attributes (properties) etc.

Comment: `Your solution is also using objects and actually a few for a single event` - not really :) Notice that all converters objects are created only once and reused for every event. So it will scale well, no matter how many events you're going to process. Having this in mind, I'd measure performance and if there's no significant difference for your use case, I'd go with the solution that you like better. I think both of them are fine.